# how can i get two asp.net user controls to talk to one another?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

i have two user controls on a .net web page and want to be able to have a  click on one control refresh the data in the other.

normally this would be simple but to complicate things i do not own the page where the two controls will be hosted. after handing them off they will be used as widgets on a page and need to interact as described above.

Comment: are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: Does it have to be a specific other control or any control of the other type?

Answer (score 1):

Will the developer of the page where the controls will be hosted be integrating them into the page and have access to the code behind?  If so, have one widget raise an event when something happens, and the other can subscribe to the event and respond. This would happen in the CodeBehind, so it would involve postbacks.

If you don't want to require postbacks, you will have to use Javascript.  But there is no reason that a custom UserControl can't have Javascript either embedded in it like any regular HTML. You can also do it from the CodeBehind using `Page.RegisterClientScript` or its several variants.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your architecture to use Web Parts Controls instead of user controls, it can be achieved easily. Take a look at this msdn post about [Web Parts Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178187.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for these controls to be added on the page multiple times? Will clicking on the one control cause a postback?

My first thought was JavaScript (you could embed the necessary JS functions in the control itself), but this would become more complicated if you can have multiple instances of your controls on the page.

Another approach would be to combine both controls into a composite control. Then you would be able to have full control over the interaction between them, because it would only be a single control at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up like this: when you click on the first control and it posts back, you loop through the `Controls` collection to find the control you want to refresh and then do whatever you need to with it. Though, if you want to do this without posting back, you'll HAVE to use a JavaScript solution.